# terraform ecs module using sub module container-definition

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-modules

I am using the following [ECS-Service terraform submodule](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ecs/blob/master/modules/service/README.md) to create the ecs service. I am also using the following [ECS-TaskDefinition submodule](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ecs/blob/master/modules/container-definition/README.md) from the same repo to generate the task-definition for the service.

the following is the task-definition

```
module "ecs_container_tr_def" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ecs/aws//modules/container-definition"
  version = "5.2.2"

  name      = "test"
  cpu       = 256
  memory    = 512
  essential = true
  image     = "1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/test:latest"
  port_mappings = [
    {
      containerPort = 5000
      hostPort      = 5000
      protocol      = "tcp"
    }
  ]
}
```

I created the service and tried to import the task definition like so:

```
module "ecs_tr_service" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ecs/aws//modules/service"
  version = "5.2.2"

  name        = "test-serv"
  cluster_arn = var.ecs_cluster_arn

  cpu    = 512
  memory = 1024

  launch_type  = "FARGATE"
  network_mode = "awsvpc"

  desired_count            = 1
  enable_autoscaling       = true
  autoscaling_min_capacity = 1
  autoscaling_max_capacity = 1

  container_definitions = {
    test = module.ecs_container_tr_def.container_definition
  }
```

The issue I have is that the `port_mapping` section in the `task-definition` is ignored for some reason and so the `apply` always fails

from the terraform plan I can see that `portMappings = []` is empty

```
# module.ecs_tr_service.aws_ecs_task_definition.this[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "this" {
      + arn                      = (known after apply)
      + arn_without_revision     = (known after apply)
      + container_definitions    = jsonencode(
            [
              + {
                  + cpu                    = 256
                  + environment            = []
                  + essential              = true
                  + image                  = "12345678.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/terrareg:latest"
                  + interactive            = false
                  + logConfiguration       = {
                      + logDriver = "awslogs"
                      + options   = {
                          + awslogs-group         = "/aws/ecs/terrareg-serv/terrareg"
                          + awslogs-region        = "eu-west-2"
                          + awslogs-stream-prefix = "ecs"
                        }
                    }
                  + memory                 = 512
                  + mountPoints            = []
                  + name                   = "terrareg"
                  + portMappings           = []
                  + privileged             = false
                  + pseudoTerminal         = false
                  + readonlyRootFilesystem = true
```

and when I do `terraform apply` I get the following error:

```
module.ecs_tr_service.aws_ecs_service.this[0]: Creating...
╷
│ Error: creating ECS Service (terrareg-serv): InvalidParameterException: The container terrareg did not have a container port 5000 defined.
│ 
│   with module.ecs_tr_service.aws_ecs_service.this[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/ecs_tr_service/modules/service/main.tf line 30, in resource "aws_ecs_service" "this":
│   30: resource "aws_ecs_service" "this" {
```

I think the issue is with the line that imports the `task-definition` into the `service` `test = module.ecs_container_tr_def.container_definition`. I have tried different ways but all have failed.

If anyone can show me how to use the `task-definition` submodule correctly and use its `output` to `import` it correctly into the `service` that would be great

the output of the module is as follows:

```
terragrunt console                                                                                            
> module.ecs_container_tr_def.container_definition
{
  "cpu" = 256
  "environment" = tolist([])
  "essential" = true
  "image" = "123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/test:latest"
  "interactive" = false
  "logConfiguration" = {
    "logDriver" = "awslogs"
    "options" = {
      "awslogs-group" = "/aws/ecs//test"
      "awslogs-region" = "eu-west-2"
      "awslogs-stream-prefix" = "ecs"
    }
  }
  "memory" = 512
  "mountPoints" = tolist([])
  "name" = "terrareg"
  "portMappings" = tolist([
    {
      "containerPort" = 5000
      "hostPort" = 5000
      "protocol" = "tcp"
    },
  ])
  "privileged" = false
  "pseudoTerminal" = false
  "readonlyRootFilesystem" = false
  "startTimeout" = 30
  "stopTimeout" = 120
  "volumesFrom" = tolist([])
}
```

Comment: Can you add the error to the question as well?

Comment: @MarkoE thanks for the suggestion ... i have updated the info to include the plan and apply with the error.

Comment: Can you try setting `create_task_definition = false` in the ECS service module call?

Comment: that gives me the error `Error: creating ECS Service (terrareg-serv): InvalidParameterException: TaskDefinition can not be blank`

Comment: Are these module calls inside of the same root module?

Comment: Yes, in the same root folder ... I think that's all okay because the `cpu`, `memory` values etc are all as expected in the plan. Its only the `port_mapping` that are blank. The only thing I can think of is that `port_mapping` is a `list` and the rest are `strings`

Comment: Can you try creating a temporary output for the `module.ecs_container_tr_def.container_definition` and see what it will show?

Comment: @MarkoE I have added the output to the original question so its easier to read. The port mapping are there as expected but I was not expecting the "tolist"

Comment: Hm, ok, and does `container_definitions = module.ecs_container_tr_def.container_definition` work?

Comment: No, I get the error: The container test did not have a container port 5000 defined. When I do apply.... │

Answer (score 0):

I think that "Container_definitions" in the "ecs_tr_service" is missing part.

**Code (ecs_tr_service part):**

```
module "ecs_tr_service" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ecs/aws//modules/service"
  version = "5.2.2"

  name        = "test-serv"
  cluster_arn = var.ecs_cluster_arn

  cpu    = 512
  memory = 1024

  launch_type  = "FARGATE"
  network_mode = "awsvpc"

  desired_count            = 1
  enable_autoscaling       = true
  autoscaling_min_capacity = 1
  autoscaling_max_capacity = 1

  container_definitions = jsonencode([{
    name  = "test"  # This should match the name in your container definition
    image = "1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/test:latest"
    portMappings = [
      {
        containerPort = 5000
        hostPort      = 5000
      }
    ]
  }])
}
```

I'm using resources directly, not modules. But I found an example for that module, here:

- https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ecs/blob/v5.2.2/examples/fargate/main.tf

**EDIT: Another Idea:**

```
# ecs_container_tr_def.tf

module "ecs_container_tr_def" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ecs/aws//modules/container-definition"
  version = "5.2.2"

  name      = "test"
  cpu       = 256
  memory    = 512
  essential = true
  image     = "1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/test:latest"
  port_mappings = [
    {
      containerPort = 5000
      hostPort      = 5000
      protocol      = "tcp"
    }
  ]
}

output "container_definition" {
  value = module.ecs_container_tr_def.container_definition
}
```

**Service:**

```
# ecs_tr_service.tf

module "ecs_tr_service" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ecs/aws//modules/service"
  version = "5.2.2"

  name        = "test-serv"
  cluster_arn = var.ecs_cluster_arn

  cpu    = 512
  memory = 1024

  launch_type  = "FARGATE"
  network_mode = "awsvpc"

  desired_count            = 1
  enable_autoscaling       = true
  autoscaling_min_capacity = 1
  autoscaling_max_capacity = 1

  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    module.ecs_container_tr_def.container_definition
  ])
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info but I am looking to use the `task definition` sub-module. 

If I add the same task definition directly using the `jsonencode` function as you did above then it works as expected.

Comment: yes `jsonencode` and that's what i am using as a work around moment

Comment: could you please test in the edit part? Output was added, and container_definition was updated..

Comment: i tried that but get the following: `Error: Iteration over non-iterable value
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/ecs_tr_service/modules/service/main.tf line 526, in module "container_definition":
│  526:   for_each = { for k, v in var.container_definitions : k => v if local.create_task_definition }`